# How to connect to an ethernet socket per browser?

Tags: javascript, sockets

I'm working on a project that involves controlling a piece of hardware over ethernet.

the remote control app should be accessible for normal browsers, tablets and possibly smartphones (and should run locally!). so as far as i see it, i'm limited to html/javascript

the device is listening on normal ethernet ports.

is there a way i can open a socket to those?

i've been reading a lot about websockets and socket.io lately, but none of them seem to really do the trick. (both require a server that understands them, which is not the case here. this device just understands plain telnet)

I'm pretty confused, as i thought that SHOULD be a pretty easy task, but right now i just don't know what to do

Comment: The standard strategy is to serve a web page from the device itself. Can you modify software on the device? If not can you package it with your own CPU/microcontroller and call the combo a "device" ?

Comment: no software/firmware modification possible... the device has to be "out of the box" (application is supposed to work on every possible configuration with just the device connected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to access a socket from within the browser directly - but you can use a proxy to do this - fire up a node-server with socket.io and pipe the data-stream to the socket.

Comment: hmm.. is it possible to have the proxy run locally? for redistribution purposes? ("here, this is the remote control, just put this folder somewhere and run it")